# How to get the current Index in an ng-repeat of a loop

Tags: angularjs

good evening, I'm currently faced with a little challenge here. 
I need to remove a checklist item from a list of section(there are list of sections and each section has a list of checklist items too). My html is shown thus.

```
<div ng-repeat="section in item.supervisionItemSectionSetupModels" >
     <div class="col-md-9 form-horizontal">
          <div class="alert alert-success">
               <strong>Checklist Section - {{$index+1}}</strong>
                    <div class="pull-right">
<a href="" ng-show="$index>0" type="button" ng-click="removeSection($index)" class="btn btn-danger" tooltip="Remove this section">
         <span class="fa fa-trash-o"></span>
           </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-4">Section Name</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-7">
                                <input name="sectionName" ng-model="section.name" placeholder="Section name" class="form-control" id="sectionName" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-9">                        
                        <table class="table">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>#</th>
                                <th width="60%">What to Check for</th>
                                <th>Options</th>
                                <th></th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            <tr ng-repeat="checklist in section.checkListItems">
                                <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="checklist.name" style="width: 100%" name="name" placeholder="Checklist Item"/>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <select class="form-control col-sm-3" ng-model="checklist.options" name="options"
                                            ng-options="option.options as option.groupName for option in checklistOption">
                                        <option value="">--Select--</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="" ng-show="$index>0" ng-click="removeCheckListItem($index)" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" tooltip="Remove this checklist">
                                        <span class="fa fa-trash-o"></span>
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                            <tfoot>
                            <tr>
                                <th colspan="3">
                                    <a href="" type="button" ng-click="addChecklistitem($index)" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" tooltip="Add New Checklist">Add</a>
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                            </tfoot>
                        </table>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-9">
                    <a href="" type="button" ng-click="addSection()" class="btn btn-success" tooltip="Add New Section">Add new section</a>

                </div>
```

While my angularJs code is(in typescript..)

```
 removeCheckListItem(index) {
        this.$scope.item.supervisionItemSectionSetupModels[index].checkListItems.splice(index, 1);
    }
    addChecklistitem(index) {
        this.$scope.item.supervisionItemSectionSetupModels[index].checkListItems.push({});
    }

    addSection(): void {
        this.$scope.item.supervisionItemSectionSetupModels.push({ checkListItems: [{}]});
    }
    removeSection(index) {
        this.$scope.item.supervisionItemSectionSetupModels.splice(index, 1);
    }
```

Each time I tried removing a checklist in a section with the index, I get this error message

Error: this.$scope.item.supervisionItemSectionSetupModels[n] is undefined

The addSection method works fine, but the remove checklist is not working
After going through my code, i discovered that in my view, the index been passed to my removeChecklistItem method is the current index of the checklist item of which it's different for the section index. You can see the method body has some issues, I've ruminated on it but it seems I'm not doing the right thing. What am I supposed to do please?

Comment: the $index in the second ng-repeat is not the same $index.  You have to use $parent.$index or $parent.$parent.$index etc...

Comment: Woow, thanks. It's now working. I actually not seen the $parent before

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant please make an answer from your comment. :)

Answer (score 0):

I replaced $index with $parent.$index and it worked fine

```
     <div ng-repeat="section in item.supervisionItemSectionSetupModels" > 
        <div class="col-md-9 form-horizontal"> 
        <div class="alert alert-success"> 
        <strong>Checklist Section - {{$index+1}}</strong> 
        <div class="pull-right"> 
        <a href="" ng-show="$index>0" type="button" ng-click="removeSection($index)" class="btn btn-danger" tooltip="Remove this section"> 
        <span class="fa fa-trash-o"></span>
         </a> 
        </div> 
        </div> 
        <div class="form-group">
         <label class="control-label col-md-4">Section Name</label> 
        <div class="col-sm-7"> 
        <input name="sectionName" ng-model="section.name" placeholder="Section name" class="form-control" id="sectionName" /> 
        </div>
         </div>
         </div> 
        <div class="col-md-9"> 
        <table class="table"> 
        <thead> 
        <tr> 
        <th>#</th>
         <th width="60%">What to Check for</th>
         <th>Options</th>
         <th></th>
         </tr> 
        </thead> 
        <tbody> 
        <tr ng-repeat="checklist in section.checkListItems"> 
        <td>{{$index+1}}</td> 
        <td> <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="checklist.name" style="width: 100%" name="name" placeholder="Checklist Item"/> </td> 
        <td> 
        <select class="form-control col-sm-3" ng-model="checklist.options" name="options" ng-options="option.options as option.groupName for option in checklistOption"> 
    <option value="">--Select--</option>
     </select> 
    </td>
     <td>
     <a href="" ng-show="$index>0" 
ng-click="removeCheckListItem($parent.$index)" 
class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" tooltip="Remove this checklist"> 
    <span class="fa fa-trash-o"></span> 
    </a> 
    </td> 
    </tr> 
    </tbody>
     <tfoot> 
    <tr> 
    <th colspan="3">
     <a href="" type="button" ng-click="addChecklistitem($index)" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" tooltip="Add New Checklist">Add</a> 
    </th>
     </tr> 
    </tfoot> 
    </table>
     </div>
     </div> 
    <div class="form-group col-md-9"> 
    <a href="" type="button" ng-click="addSection()" class="btn btn-success" tooltip="Add New Section">Add new section</a> 
    </div>
```